# How to implement a 3 level dropdown with optgroup in yii?

Tags: yii, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor, multi-level, optgroup

I need a drop down like following using yii.

Main

---Main-sub1

-----   main-sub-sub1

-----   main-sub-sub2

-------     main-sub-sub-sub1

---Main-sub2

---Main-sub3

........

In this, all levels must be selectable because I may add more sub levels to any main category if needed at any time. So main categories also must be selectable.

Please help!

Comment: You cant' have nested optgroups. Perhaps you can try using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Select2 with yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/) is the best known solution. So far it works only for 2 levels. In the given link you might find also a 2 dimentional optgroup setting.

If you need a 3-level selection, then use two level select2 and [a dependent dropdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/creating-a-dependent-dropdown/) for a 3rd level.

### Update

Use [Yii TreeView](https://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=yii%20treeview) functionality then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have to choose parent also, but here I am not able to choose parent.